# XSL 2.0 - Apply a predicate on all elements of a group

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have such nodes:

```
<Node name="_1" W="0" n=".2" L="A" ProcessTime="56" units="ms"/>
<Node name="_2" W="0" n=".8" L="B" ProcessTime="6" units="us"/>
```

grouped by attribute L. My goal is to write a one-liner to get value of `n * ProcessTime * units`

To get multiplier for units I also have a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="units">
    <multiplier ns="1E-9" ms="1E-3" us="1E-6"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

in scope of grouping for-each-group loop.

Currently I have this expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/(@numberOfVisits * @ProcessTime * $units/multiplier/@*[name()=current()/@units]))"/>
```

It works, but uses the `@units` value only of the 1st element, applying it on every other element of `current-group()`

The question is: how do i make this expression to use individual `@units` value of every element in group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for .. return ..` expression like `sum(for $node in current-group() return $node/(@numberOfVisits .. $units/ multiplier/@*[name() = $node/@units]))`